# Receiving POST Request on a page that is never loaded

Tags: c#, post, event-handling, request

I'm in kind of a bind and I need your wisdom.

1) There's this website, which is not managed by me, that sends MY WEBSITE a POST request. This POST request contains XML.

2) The page, on my website, that receives the POST request (my callback page) is never accessed by anyone, in other words, the user is not redirected to this page. Meaning that the Page_Load event is never fired (?? am i wrong here?).

3) I need to be able to capture that request and the XML data that is attached to it.

Questions:

-How can you capture a post request if the page_load event is never fired? I'm not familiar with this.

-If there is a way of debugging this, any input/resources are welcome.

Thank you in advance!

NOTE: I know this question is a duplicate/rework of one of my other questions and I am really sorry for this, but the other one was put on hold... I need some knowledge. I can't seem to find a solution with this. Please understand and try not to be upset... I don't know what else to do..

I don't want someone to give me the entire solution on a silver plate. Hell no. I just want some knowledge, some insight, just something that will lead me towards the right direction.

EDIT:

Well, the third party site got back to me and told me that the XML is crypted in the URL and that it was associated with this parameter: trx_xml.

Does this mean that it's not really placed in a inputStream?

Comment: `Page_Load` will fire in response to any HTTP request.  However, you should use an ASHX.

Comment: I will research ASHX, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was errors on both fronts. The Payment gateway's documentation was not up-to-date and my callback url was cached in the browser and was not good. We got everything working in the end. Thank you to everyone who took the time to help me.